# $P(2X+2Y=28)$ Poisson Variable Distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

> Let $X$ be a random poisson variable with the parameter $5$, let $Y$ be a random poisson variable with the parameter $10$. $X, Y$ are independent of each other.
>
> What is the probability that $2(X+Y) = 28?$

**My Approach**
Let $Z=2(X+Y)$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are indepenent variables and and indepedent on each other, $Z$ is a poisson random variable with the parameter $\lambda_Z = \lambda_X + \lambda_Y = 15$.

Therefore we can use the poisson probability function -

$$P(Z=28)=P(2X+2Y=28) = e^{-15} \cdot \frac{15^{28}}{28!} = 0.00085$$

However I'm afraid I'm wrong here. What do I do with the $2$ here? If I had only $X+Y$ I would be pretty sure I'm right, but I am not sure.

Should I multiplie the result on $2$?

Thank you!

Comment: $$2x+2y=28 \iff x+y=14$$

Comment: So my final result should be multiplied by 2?

Comment: no just calculate the probability of $X+Y$ equal to $14$

Comment: Or look it in this way $Z=X+Y$ so you are asked to find the probability of $2Z=28$

Comment: If $X, Y$ are independent Poisson, then $2(X+Y)$ is _not_ Poisson, since its value is always an even integer (but Poisson variables might be odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ have Poisson-distribution with rates $\lambda_X$, $\lambda_Y$ and are independent then $X+Y$ has Poisson-distribution with rate $\lambda_X+\lambda_Y$.

This can be exploited to find: $$P(2(X+Y)=28)=P(X+Y=14)$$

Observe for $Z:=2(X+Y)$ we have $P(Z=n)=0$ if $n$ is odd, showing that it has **not** Poisson-distribution.

Comment: Thank you! got it.

Comment: You are welcome.